# regarding hascode equalities of two object

Tags: java, hashcode

I have the below question ask in interview please advise whhich are the correct options..

Given  two objects a and b of the same class, and if equals() and hashCode() are implemented correctly for that class, which  of the following must hold  true?
Multiple options can be correct (Check ANY that apply)

1. If a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() then a.equals(b)
2. If a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() then !a.equals(b)
3. If a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() then a.equals(b)
4. If a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() then !a.equals(b)

now please advise which multiple options are correct.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers in square brackets.

```
If a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() then a.equals(b) [could be or could not be]
If a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() then !a.equals(b) [could be or could not be]
If a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() then a.equals(b) [FALSE]
If a.hashCode() != b.hashCode() then !a.equals(b) [TRUE]
```

All of this is succinctly explained in this article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the hashCode() and equals() methods are used when storing and when looking up objects in a hashtable.

Here are two rules that are good to know about implementing the hashCode() method in your own classes, if the hashtables in the Java Collections API are to work correctly:

1. If object1 and object2 are equal according to their equals() method,
   they must also have the same hash code.
2. If object1 and object2 have the same hash code, they do NOT have to
   be equal too.

In shorter words:

1. If equal, then same hash codes too.
2. Same hash codes no guarantee of being equal.